# Setting a default layout in the controller (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'd like to set a default layout in my BaseController, so that it is used for every view I have. I don't want to use "@extends" in every single view.

In Laravel 4 this was easy to do. Now I can't find any way to do this in Laravel 5.2 .

Does anyone have an idea?

BTW: this is my first question on stackoverflow, I hope i'm following the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Kind of dumb of me not to look deeper into the Laravel 4 code. I thought layouts were chained somewhere deep in the core, but it was just the Controller, which has a "callAction" function. This function sets up the layout and then calls the right method.

Below is the code for this, taken from here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-this-layout-content-not-working

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller {

protected $layout = 'core::layouts.default';

/**
 * Show the user profile.
 */
public function setContent($view, $data = [])
{

    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        return $this->layout->nest('child', $view, $data);
    }

    return view($view, $data);

}

/**
 * Set the layout used by the controller.
 *
 * @param $name
 * @return void
 */
protected function setLayout($name)
{
    $this->layout = $name;
}

/**
 * Setup the layout used by the controller.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = view($this->layout);
    }
}


public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    $this->setupLayout();

    $response = call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $parameters);


    if (is_null($response) && ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $response = $this->layout;
    }

    return $response;
}
}
```